# Django: How to get all objects related to a model by another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have 3 models: `User`, `Course` and `Homework`.
Each course has some homework and some users(students). How can I have all homeworks of all courses a user is in? These are the models:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    # ...

class Course(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='student_courses')
    # ...

class Homework(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='course_homeworks')
    # ...
```

Comment: The first thing I do with such requirements is to design the data model. It sounds like many students can enroll in many courses (UsersInCourse), and that many students can be assigned many units of homework (AssignedHomework). With that in mind, I'd create a many-to-many relationship for both (which will mean a M2M table for each). Then, I can query for UsersInCourse and AssignedHomework. With any such situation though, time spent planning, combined with the journey of building both the logic and presentation has shown me that there are many ways to accomplish the same objective in coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Homework.objects.filter(course__students=user)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have user object you could do like

```py
Homework.objects.filter(course__students=user)
```

if you have user id you could do like

```py
Homework.objects.filter(course__student_courses__id=user_id)
```

i used `student_courses` in the above code because you set the `related_name`

you could also do this if you have multiple user or user id

```py
Homework.objects.filter(course__student_courses__in=user_ids) # user_ids = [1,3,4]
```

So you can use any of the user fields to filter to by just replacing
`course__student_courses__id` with `course__student_courses__field_name`

One last thing you can also us `startswith, exact, iexact, ...` like `course__student_courses__field_name__startswith`